# How to display and update .txt file in batch

Tags: file, batch-file, text

I am using a program where it requires me to use a command prompt and I need to log everything in a `.txt` file (I already have it logging). But I need it to display and update the text in the command prompt. I only want to show the latest text from the `.txt` file. How do I do that?

Comment: Please provide code you have tried so far!

Comment: Provide code as previously suggested and define what you mean by "latest text". Do you mean only the last line? If so what if the last line is blank? Or perhaps you are executing commands and want all of the text for that command to be displayed and logged??? If so, log to a temp file, type the temp file to display, append temp file to your log. End by deleting the temp file (so you don't get a duplicate in the log in case the next command generates no output).

Comment: ok the line is java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar cb.jar i have tried appending it and type but i do not want to overwrite the log when I do
Type AllLog.txt
the screen closes and when I do
(with At sign)echo off
type AllLog.txt
:top
cls
goto top
It still does not work I have created a program that uses the same thing i need a while ago but i lost the code for it @RGuggisberg I also tried java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar cb.jar >> AllLog.txt

Comment: We are still just guessing without any code to work with. Try ECHO(java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar cb.jar >> AllLog.txt. Or manually edit the text file (which you have not shown us either). Are you sure the text file is not empty?

Comment: the text file is not empty but it does not display the text on the cmd prompt
the java string is supposed to only display and not log @RGuggisberg

Comment: Is it pure ascii text or unicode? Generate a text file with notepad that contains what you think should be in there and try using that. Also compare size of Noepad generated file with your current one. Is one 2x the size of the other?

Comment: Without the code and the text file we are just wasting time. Please provide as has been asked twice already and then maybe someone else can help.